# How Do I Collect Redstone Ore in Minecraft PE?

Tags: minecraft-redstone, minecraft-bedrock-edition

Is this supposed to happen when mining Redstone ore in mine craft PE

- Every time I try to mine Redstone ore in mine craft PE it won't let me collect it
- It lights up the room and then turns dark again
- Deletes the block when I hit it

Answer (score 0):

1. the redstone ore is not currently fully implemented, so you should just leave it alone until Mojang updates the PE with redstone dust.
2. Redstone Ore has the unique property of providing a faint light when hit. The little will go out after a few seconds.
3. I am not sure about this one.

Comment: 3. might be if using a lower than iron pickaxe, it just breaks leaving no dust behind.

Answer (score 0):

The update 0.8.0 will let you delete it and get it so just leave it alone intill you get that update